# fast access to subset of items when filtering along three dimensions

Tags: multidimensional-array, data-structures, filter

This isn't a coding question so much as a logic one.  I am tasked with showing a list of documents based on choices made from three dropdowns, one per document attribute.  The attributes are client, document type and document category.  Because the default view is "All" for all three, I will be fetching all documents from a database initially.

I'd like to store that list in a local data structure so that each time the user filters the results based on dropdown selections, I can quickly pull the results and display them.  Since there may literally be thousands of clients and document categories, it strikes me that a three-dimensional array would become too cumbersome.  Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are documents added and removed frequently? Or do you mostly have a static set? Also, do you need to worry about the case where there are more than three attributes?

Comment: The set is static, and no need to worry about more than three attributes.  Whatever gets pulled from the database is what's filterable.

Comment: How many values can these attributes take?

Comment: One attribute may have hundreds, one may have even 2000 - 3000 and the last only about 30 maximum

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an [embedded (in-memory) database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database), e.g. H2, HSQLDB, or SQLite - this way the database is responsible for the indexing, and because it's an in-memory database you don't have the cost of repeated disk accesses.

A second option would be to maintain a `Map<key, Set<data>>` for each attribute and to then take the set intersection of the three retrieved sets (`mapA.get("A").intersection(mapB.get("B").intersection(mapC.get("C")))`) which will run in around `O(n)` time where `n` is the total size of the three retrieved sets.

Finally, there are multi-dimensional indexing data structures such as [k-d trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) that can be used to perform a range search.  They're not included in most standard language libraries, but several languages have open-source implementations available via github or wherever.

My preference would be to use the `Map<key, Set<data>>` if there are only three attributes being indexed, and to use an embedded database or a k-d tree if there are more than six or seven attributes being indexed.

Comment: i haven't worked with maps before, so are you saying you'd set up a map for each attribute, where the attribute corresponded with the key and the Set would be all the documents for that attribute/key?

Comment: @neil1967 Yup, assuming you're using a `HashMap` then retrieval will run in average O(1) time.  You can use the [Guava Sets class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html) to compute set intersections.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  One other question.  I don't know if it was clear that a user can select more than 1 key from each attribute.  Would I have to do multiple intersection calls to cover all permutations?  For example, (mapA.get("A").intersection(mapB.get("A").intersection(mapC.get("A")))), then (mapA.get("A").intersection(mapB.get("A").intersection(mapC.get("B")))) and so on...?

Comment: @neil1967 You'd union the sets from the same attribute, then you'd take the intersection of the three unioned sets: setA = mapA.get("A").union(mapA.get("B")); setB = mapB.get("A").union(mapB.get("B")); setC = mapC.get("A").union(mapC.get("B")); intersect = setA.intersection(setB.intersection(setC))

Comment: ah, excellent.  as I was awaiting your response, I began to wonder about using linq queries.  If I have the entire document set to begin, couldn't I also take the approach of doing a linq query of the whole set?  I know this strays from your suggestion, and I don't know if you have used linq for this purpose, but is it an efficient solution?

Comment: @neil1967 Do you mean using linq to perform the intersection/union?  That makes sense - I hadn't realized you were using .NET, whereas Guava is a Java solution to the problem